# Como agregar "," (comas) a un valor numerico ya agregador en la base de datos

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Hola como puedo traer un dato numerico y que me le ponga comas (,) **ejemplo:** 1000000 y que me le ponga sus respectivas comas 1,000,000

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual con ese input  y otro me generan en automatico 3 respuestas pero si cambio el type="number" por type="text" me lo toma como si fuera punto (.)

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importe Asegurado</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"><input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();" name="importe" class="form-control m-b"></div>
```

Ya intente cambiando en la base de datos el tipo de columba por varchar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi tabla solo uso php para jalar el dato ¿necesito algun script?

```html
<tr class="gradeA" style="text-align:center;">
                            <td><?php echo $row["idViaje"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["FechaAlta"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["folio"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["Cliente"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$ "; ?><?php echo $row["total"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "$ "; ?><?php echo $row["importe"]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que no alteres tus datos. Lo que quieres hacer es algo que pertenece al formato de los datos, no a los datos en sí. Si alteras tus datos luego tendrás problemas cuando quieras hacer cálculos con ellos y demás. Haber metido el símbolo de la moneda ahí también es un gravísimo error, como lo es también convertir la columna a tipo  `VARCHAR`. Cuando mañana te pidan que organices los datos por importe asegurado te darás cuenta del grave error que has cometido. O cuando te pidan que sumes importes. Debes tener claro que el formato es una cosa y los datos son otra cosa, no mezcles

Comment: El simbolo de la moneda $ solo lo meti visualmente no interviene con los datos, converti la columna a VARCHAR para ver si se podia agregar la coma que es lo que quiero o como comentaba si habia alguna conversion (visualizacion) para la coma (,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendaría que:

- No intentes cambiar el tipo de columna de la base de datos a `VARCHAR`
- No guardes el símbolo de la moneda en la base de datos
- No guardes números formateados en la base de datos

Es muy importante distinguir entre lo que es un *formato* y lo que son los datos en sí. Los formatos son formas de representar los datos, de ahí se deduce que un mismo dato puede ser representando en múltiples formas. Por eso, **guardar datos formateados es un grave error** porque ya pierdes flexibilidad y esos datos no pueden ser representados de otra manera. Además ocurren cosas más graves: si hay que calcular, ordenar, comparar en base a esos datos que guardaste formateados, todas esas operaciones se revelan imposibles.

Las bases de datos existen para guardar los datos en su realidad misma y luego por programación les das el formato que quieras. Por tanto la realidad misma de tu número es esta:

- `10000      -- INT`

O esta:

- `10000.00   -- DECIMAL`

Así es como el dato debería existir en la base de datos, luego si quieres ponerle separadores o lo que sea, los lenguajes de programación y hasta la misma base de datos, tienen funciones para eso.

---

### ¿Cómo formatear los datos entonces?

Para el caso de PHP, que es el que nos ocupa, existe la función  **[`number_format`]**[1](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php). A partir de ella, puedes formatear cualquier valor `$n`.

La función admite los siguientes parámetros:

- El número que se quiere formatear, que sería en tu caso el valor de la columna obtenido de la base de datos
- Cuántas posiciones decimales quieres para tu número (en este caso usaremos `2`)
- Separador de posiciones decimales (en este caso usaremos el punto `.`)
- Separador de miles (en este caso usaremos la coma `,`)

Veremos también casos cambiando los caracteres, sólo para que veas la flexibilidad que admiten este tipo de funciones de formateo.

```
$n= 10000.00;
$n1 = number_format($n,2, '.', ',');
$n2 = number_format($n,2, '.', ' ');
$n3 = number_format($n,2, ',', '.');
$n4 = number_format($n);

echo $n1.PHP_EOL;
echo $n2.PHP_EOL;
echo $n3.PHP_EOL;
echo $n4.PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
10,000.00
10 000.00
10.000,00
10,000
```

Tenemos el **mismo dato, representado de 4 formas distintas**. El formato es una realidad subjetiva, por eso no puede nunca ser reflejado en el dato como entidad. El dato es algo así como un ente metafísico, que debe existir *sin ningún tipo de adorno*  en la base de datos. Adornarlo es un grave error, porque supone sacrificar los datos y hasta la herramienta que usas para guardarlos (es el típico ejemplo de usar un VARCHAR para guardar fechas o números).

Aparte de lo ya dicho, otra herramienta potente a la que se renuncia al cometer errores como estos es al **control de errores**, en los cálculos, en los valores mismos de las fechas por ejemplo, en un `VARCHAR` puedes introducir una fecha como `20195050`, *el día 50 del mes 50 de 2019*, y no hay forma de enterarse o de controlar fácilmente que se ha introducido un dato erróneo.

¿Y el signo `$`? Imagino que ya sabrás cómo mostrarlo. Además, también existen funciones para monedas si fuera preciso.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Cedano me sirvio tu regañada xD con el codigo php de ejemplo que me diste ya logre que se visualicen con comas ,  <td><?php echo "$ "; ?><?php echo number_format($row["importe"],2, '.', ','); ?></td>

Comment: @IsaiasAlejandroSanchez no tenía intención de regañarte :) La idea era que captaras la diferencia entre un formato y un dato en sí mismo. Muchas veces se cometen errores de diseño por esa causa, y no solo en bases de datos, sino en muchos otros campos como diseño de Clases, etc .